# Philicorda phase shifter vibrato circuit doesnt work

Tags: phase, multivibrator

I have built this circuit in the online editor, but it doesn't seem to oscillate.

My philicorda vibrato broke down and i want to repair it. It should convert 21V DC into a sine wave when i understand it correctly.

But [my online circuit simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2012.050203812241895%2072%205%2050%0AR%20112%2096%20112%2048%200%200%2040%2020%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20112%2096%20112%20160%200%203000%0Aw%20-192%20352%20-160%20352%200%0Ac%20-160%20352%20-96%20352%200%204.7e-11%206.640126274127475%0Ac%20-96%20352%20-32%20352%200%204.7e-11%20-0.000002998905042517208%0Ac%20-32%20352%2032%20352%200%204.7e-11%20-0.6287438280781092%0Aw%2032%20352%2032%20272%200%0Aw%2032%20272%2032%20208%200%0Ac%2032%20208%20112%20208%200%201e-11%20-6.01137945600067%0Ar%2032%20272%20112%20272%200%201500000%0At%2032%20352%20112%20352%200%201%20-6.01137945600067%200.6287438140165715%20900%0Aw%20112%20272%20112%20336%200%0Aw%20112%20208%20112%20272%200%0Aw%2064%20160%20112%20160%200%0Aw%20112%20160%20112%20208%200%0Aw%20112%20368%20112%20400%200%0Ar%20-96%20352%20-96%20400%200%2022000%0Ar%20-32%20352%20-32%20400%200%2022000%0Aw%20-32%20400%20112%20400%200%0Aw%20-96%20400%20-32%20400%200%0Ar%20112%20400%20112%20448%200%201000%0Ag%20112%20480%20112%20512%200%0Aw%20-192%20160%2064%20160%200%0Ar%20320%20432%20320%20496%200%201000000%0Ag%20192%20464%20192%20496%200%0A209%20112%20400%20192%20400%200%200.00015%201.1708721823367452%201%0Ar%20-192%20352%20-192%20160%200%201%0A174%20192%20400%20240%20464%200%204700%200.005%20Resistance%0A209%20320%20432%20240%20432%200%200.00015%20-1.0000057041045516%201%0Ag%20320%20496%20320%20512%200%0As%20320%20432%20384%20432%200%200%20false%0Ar%20400%20432%20400%20512%200%20680%0Ag%20400%20512%20400%20528%200%0Ag%20448%20512%20448%20528%200%0Aw%20112%20448%20112%20480%200%0Aw%20384%20432%20400%20432%200%0Aw%20400%20432%20448%20432%200%0Aw%20448%20432%20512%20432%200%0A209%20448%20432%20448%20512%200%200.0000047%200.33111098249981297%201%0Ar%20512%20432%20576%20432%200%201000%0Ag%20576%20432%20592%20432%200%0Ao%200%2032%200%204099%2020%200.00625%200%202%200%203%0Ao%2037%2032%200%204099%201.25%200.0015625%200%202%2037%203%0A) does not oscillate, why is that?

[philicorda 752 service manual](http://www.peel.dk/Philips/Philicorda_GM752_service_manual.pdf)

**Solution**: I used the wrong capacitor values in the simulation. Also the service manual was showing the output capacitor in the wrong polarity, it needs to go with the negative side towards ground. Thanks for all the help :) ! [working simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+42.05934401203833+72+5+50%0AR+112+96+112+48+0+0+40+20+0+0+0.5%0Ar+112+96+112+160+0+3000%0Aw+-192+352+-160+352+0%0Ac+-160+352+-96+352+0+4.7000000000000005e-7+2.568283392676392%0Ac+-96+352+-32+352+0+4.7000000000000005e-7+-2.026218937376459%0Ac+-32+352+32+352+0+4.7000000000000005e-7+-0.8692830612411857%0Aw+32+352+32+272+0%0Aw+32+272+32+208+0%0Ac+32+208+112+208+0+1e-8+0.3273232193641742%0Ar+32+272+112+272+0+1500000%0At+32+352+112+352+0+1+0.3273232193641742+0.6393828873374594+900%0Aw+112+272+112+336+0%0Aw+112+208+112+272+0%0Aw+64+160+112+160+0%0Aw+112+160+112+208+0%0Aw+112+368+112+400+0%0Ar+-96+352+-96+400+0+22000%0Ar+-32+352+-32+400+0+22000%0Aw+-32+400+112+400+0%0Aw+-96+400+-32+400+0%0Ar+112+400+112+448+0+1000%0Ag+112+480+112+512+0%0Aw+-192+160+64+160+0%0Ar+320+432+320+496+0+1000000%0Ag+192+464+192+496+0%0A209+112+400+192+400+0+0.00015+3.0916346554297567+1%0Ar+-192+352+-192+160+0+1%0A174+192+400+240+464+0+4700+0.005+Vibrato+Depth%0A209+240+432+320+432+0+0.00015+-0.04897732866104432+1%0Ag+320+496+320+512+0%0As+320+432+448+432+0+0+false%0Ar+448+432+448+512+0+680%0Ag+448+512+448+528+0%0Ag+496+512+496+528+0%0Aw+112+448+112+480+0%0Aw+448+432+496+432+0%0A209+496+432+496+512+0+0.0000047+0.6013169505926946+1%0Ar+512+432+576+432+0+1000%0Ag+576+432+592+432+0%0Ax+201+187+510+190+4+24+Philicorda%5Cs752%5CsVibrato%5CsCircuit%0Ax+335+412+473+415+4+24+vibrato%5Cson/off%0Ax+144+479+282+482+4+24+vibrato%5Csdepth%0Aw+512+432+496+432+0%0Ax+160+370+422+373+4+12+%3C-%5CsManual%5Csshows%5Csthis%5Cscapacitor%5Csin%5Cswrong%5Csdirection%0Ao+0+256+0+4099+20+0.0125+0+2+0+3%0Ao+35+256+0+4099+1.25+0.0015625+0+2+35+3%0A)

**Update:** Turns out the cap was shown in the correct polarity in the manual - as on the physical board. I just had a too low reverse voltage set in the simulation. Also: this was actually the cap that was blown and caused the vibrato in my Philicorda to fail. Because its only rated for 4V. I replaced it with a 16V cap that should be able to deal with more reverse voltage.

[image]

Comment: So what is your question? You haven't asked one. If you don't have an oscillosope then you should annotate the diagram with the DC voltage measurements you take - particularly on each of the transistor pins. We would also need to know the input impedance of your multimeter to allow for the loading effect. If you have used alternate components we'd need to know that too.

Comment: Also, your schematic is different from the original schematic.

Comment: @Schnitz: Who is that comment addressed to? Neither of us mentioned C414. If this is information relevant to your question then hit the edit link and add it in.

Comment: Check that the transistor model you used in your sim has enough gain. This [datasheet](https://alltransistors.com/transistor.php?transistor=22345) for a BC148**C** says it has a minimum hFE of 450.

Comment: @brhans I have set a beta of 900 for this transistor so that should work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your capacitor values are too small. 10K equals 10nF, 10K means 10000 pF.

470K == 470 nF

It is a phase-shift oscillator, and the positive feedback has to be about 1 or just a bit more than 1 (self triggered oscillation), so your active part, the amplification of your transistor is important. Can you choose a similar transistor in your simulation. Also there have to be some noise figure to start sinus oscillation - I don't know if your simulation program is capable to create this transient phase.

Comment: Ok thanks for spotting this. I replaced the capacitors with the correct values. But it still doesnt oscillate. http://tinyurl.com/yb6hw9rr

Comment: Btw i used this online calculator which says 470K is 47pF ?
https://www.electronics2000.co.uk/calc/capacitor-code-calculator.php

Comment: I think the online calculator doesn't support this "K" values. Often capacitors are labeled with values based to pF. It is very idle to write about these values, In the very past, capacitors were even labled with "cm" but meant with 1 cm in CGS-system with 1.1 pF within our prefered SI system,

Comment: Thanks @TomKuschel it works now :) Crazy old times thats just too hard to make sense of these service manuals as an amateur

Comment: @SchnitzelPanic In this case, "K" is not the tolerance but a multiplier. Hence 470K = 470pF *1000 = 470nF

Comment: Ah ok, same as resistors basically

Comment: @SchnitzelPanic - if you look at the last page in the service manual you can see that they're using the 'K' as a multiplier and specifying the tolerance separately.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove this 10pF capacitor from the circuit. Or increase the 47pF capacitors values (all three). Because now with that low capacitor values in 3xRC filter the10pF will kill all the amplifier voltage gain.

[Circuit sim](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+42.05934401203833+72+5+50%0AR+112+96+112+48+0+0+40+20+0+0+0.5%0Ar+112+96+112+160+0+3000%0Aw+-192+352+-160+352+0%0Ac+-160+352+-96+352+0+4.7000000000000005e-7+12.17700204078117%0Ac+-96+352+-32+352+0+4.7000000000000005e-7+-1.0012369781312507%0Ac+-32+352+32+352+0+4.7000000000000005e-7+-0.8505470331288478%0Aw+32+352+32+272+0%0Aw+32+272+32+208+0%0Ac+32+208+112+208+0+1e-8+-10.325176118608521%0Ar+32+272+112+272+0+1500000%0At+32+352+112+352+0+1+-10.325176118608521+0.6183084885228061+200%0Aw+112+272+112+336+0%0Aw+112+208+112+272+0%0Aw+64+160+112+160+0%0Aw+112+160+112+208+0%0Aw+112+368+112+400+0%0Ar+-96+352+-96+400+0+33000%0Ar+-32+352+-32+400+0+22000%0Aw+-32+400+112+400+0%0Aw+-96+400+-32+400+0%0Ar+112+400+112+448+0+1000%0Ag+112+480+112+512+0%0Aw+-192+160+64+160+0%0Ar+320+432+320+496+0+1000000%0Ag+192+464+192+496+0%0A209+112+400+192+400+0+0.00015+2.3177837268645263+1%0Ar+-192+352+-192+160+0+1%0A174+192+400+240+464+0+4700+0.005+Resistance%0A209+240+432+320+432+0+0.00015+-0.5932051076671084+1%0Ag+320+496+320+512+0%0As+320+432+384+432+0+0+false%0Ar+400+432+400+512+0+680%0Ag+400+512+400+528+0%0Ag+448+512+448+528+0%0Aw+112+448+112+480+0%0Aw+384+432+400+432+0%0Aw+400+432+448+432+0%0Aw+448+432+512+432+0%0A209+448+432+448+512+0+0.0000047+0.2011895501251641+1%0Ar+512+432+576+432+0+1000%0Ag+576+432+592+432+0%0Ao+0+256+0+4099+20+0.00625+0+2+0+3%0Ao+37+256+0+4099+1.25+0.00078125+0+2+37+3%0A)

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain why you think this should work?

Comment: @Transistor 10pF kills all HF gain. Notice 47pF capacitors in the 3xRC filter.

Comment: Put it in your answer not sprinkled through the comments!

Comment: But this is the orignal Philips manufactuer circuit ? It should work this way ?

Comment: @SchnitzelPanic But the Phillips doesn't use 47pF in 3xRC filter. They use 470nF

Comment: @SchnitzelPanic I fix your simulation file.

Comment: @G36 but your simulation still doesnt oscillate. Also, i want the original schema to work. So i cannot change any components that was just an error by myself in not understanding what 470K means.

Comment: @SchnitzelPanic See this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q66cn.png As you can see it  oscillate

Comment: @G36 which link are you refering to ? the one in the answer doesnt work for me

Comment: @SchnitzelPanic Strange for me it works without any problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q66cn.png

Comment: @SchnitzelPanic Try press restart button

Comment: Ok here is a working link. http://tinyurl.com/ycg247ow
I did the same think like you, flipping the output capacitor. So does that mean the original schematic from philiphs is wrong ?

And why did you use 4.7nF instead of 470nF ?

Comment: Well, not wrong but simple errors happen quite often in the service manual. And I use 4.7nF for convenience.

Comment: Ok thanks can you update the url in your answer ? it still points to an old circuit

Comment: Turns out the cap is actually correct in the manual, i.e. same as on the physical board.

Comment: They are in picofarad?